# Action called in componentWillReceiveProps goes in an infinite loop.

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

In my app, there are stages and games corresponding to a stage.I fetch the stage in componentDidMount and then in componentWillReceiveProps, I check if there is stageId in reducer, then fetch games for stage.The action used to fetch games for stage is being triggered infinite times.Can someone explain why?

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchCurrentStage();
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextState) {
  if (nextState.stageReducer && nextState.stageReducer.stageId) {
    this.props.fetchGamesForStage(nextState.stageReducer.stageId);// Corresponding action is triggered infinite times.Why?
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` the values of `nextStage.stageReducer` and `nextState.stageReducer.stageId`?  If the action is being called in an infinite loop then that condition must be true every time you update the state and trigger a re-render.

Comment: Now, I don't know your whole app logic. But you are calling a function from the parent `fetchCurrentStage()`, when the child is mounted. Wouldn't it be better to just fetch it directly from the parent and pass the result down as a prop? This wouldn't solve your issue - just an observation I made.

Comment: Also, `nextState` should probably be called `nextProps`?

Comment: can you share your `mapStateToProps` function?

Comment: @RiteshBansal `const mapStateToProps = ({ stageReducer }) => ({ stageReducer });`

Comment: Donot trigger action in componentWillReceiveProps. This is incorrect. Props are updated when action is triggered. I'm sure the action needs to be called somewhere else. The action will in turn update store and this event will be fired again causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, `I check if there is stageId in reducer`, I am assuming that you have written your `mapStateToProps` function something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    stageReducer: state.stageReducer,
  }
}
```

It would be great if you write `mapStateToProps`  something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    stageId: state.stageReducer ? state.stageReducer.stateId : undefined,
  }
}
```

Just pass `stageId` from `stateReducer` not whole `stateReducer` and you can compare older `stateId` with new `stageId` in `componentWillReceiveProps` like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.stageId && this.props.stageId !== nextProps.stageId) {
      this.props.fetchGamesForStage(nextState.stageId);// Corresponding action is triggered infinite times.Why?
    }
}
```

When first-time `componentWillreceiveProps` is called, `this.props.stageId !== nextProps.stageId` will be evaluated to true. So, corresponding action will be triggered.

**A doubt:** I think you are changing in the reference of `stageReducer` when the result of `fetchGamesForStage` is fetched from the server. That's why `componentWillReceiveProps` is again called.

If this is correct, then send selected items from `stageReducer` from `mapStateToProps`

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
       // other things from stageReducer

        stageId: state.stageReducer ? state.stageReducer.stateId : undefined,
      }
    }
```

Or if you do not want to change your structure, then this may also help:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  const oldStageId = this.props.stageReducer ? this.props.stageReducer.stageId : undefined
  const newStageId = newProps.stageReducer ? newProps.stageReducer.stageId : undefined
  if (newStageId && oldStageId !== newStageId) {
    this.props.fetchGamesForStage(newStageId);// Corresponding action is triggered infinite times.Why?
  }
}
```

Hope, it helps.